# Is it possible to create add people from outside the company inside AD mailinglists?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, ldap, mailing-list

I would like to know if it is possible to add people from outside your company inside you AD so they can be added as members of different mailing lists.

Clearly, I am looking for a safe way of doing this, one that would not mean that they will become real AD users.

Here is the complete use-case: I am using Jira with an Active Directory/LDAP integration, so people from inside the company would not have to ask to create accounts for them. Also, we do map Exchange Mailinglists to JIRA groups, so people can change access permissions based on memberships.

Still, the same instance is also used by external people, people that can register to have new accounts. Now these accounts are kept locally but this means that if we want to create groups for them, we need to to this from inside JIRA, and Jira allows only administrators to manager groups.

Instead, Exchange Mailinglists do have a big advantage, they can be managed by their owners or by IT department.

Now, I am looking for an approach that would allow me to apply a similar solution for external accounts (Obviously group creation would be assumed to be something that can be done only by insiders).

Is this possible, how?

Answer (score 6):

You can create Contacts in AD and add them to Distribution Groups, that sounds quite similar to what you're after

Comment: Can you please give me some hints regarding how does this work. Imagine that JIRA wants to be allowed to create accounts into AD/LDAP. It is possible to allow a service account to create Contacts (not users) using LDAP interface and to have these Contacts by default? My only experience with AD is via LDAP and I cannot control it other way. Clearly, I do not want to create accounts manually for people that are registering. Any, reference would be more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be done from within Jira, I've only done that at the AD level before  I'm not sure how or if jira would see them. Sorry!